# Weird integral curve on GeoGebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, math-software, plane-curves, online-resources

I graphed the direction field of the differential equation at [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc) 
$$y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$$ and here is the result:

[image]

Both the direction field and the integral curve passing through $(1,1)$ look fine, but there is a really weird curve $(2,-1)$; I am almost certain it is incorrect even without calculation. May I know the cause of the problem and how to fix it (other than simply remove it)?

Comment: Clearly a software bug.  I don't know GeoGebra, but perhaps there is an option for a finer grid spacing.

Comment: I googled and picked the following website out of several: At this one you could adjust the step (e.g. 0.1 or 0.01 etc) and the method (Euler or Runge-Kutta variations). Runge-Kutta with step 0.01 gives a reasonably looking curve through (2,-1) (though it gives two curves, and I think it should only be one, so I guess the jagged part it still present, though falls outside of the viewing window). https://bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html

Answer (score 6):

Note that the differential equation is undefined on the line $x+y=0$, with $|dy/dx|\to \infty$ as you approach that line.  Numerical solvers can do funny things when they approach a singularity.

Instead of this differential equation, you might look at the system
$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{dy}{dt} &= x-y\cr
             \dfrac{dx}{dt} &= x+y\cr}$$
The solutions of your differential equation correspond to trajectories of this system, except that the solutions of the differential equation cease to exist when they hit $x+y=0$, while the trajectories of the system just change the sign of $dx/dt$.

Comment: To underscore this point, the Bluffton solver includes an option to numerically solve a 2-by-2 system of ODEs. Some quick experimentation shows that, while Bluffton gives bad integral curves for default settings when doing $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x+y}{x-y}$, it gives sensible integral curves when solving it as a system. Thus the 2D approach really does make things substantially simpler numerically.

Answer (score 3):

There are already good comments and an answer.

You should try another solver like [*Bluffton*](https://bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html).

Mathematica also produces (notice the line $y = -x$)

[image]

The Mathematica code to generate this is

```
  pl = Plot[-x, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red];

  sp = StreamPlot[{1, (x - y)/(x + y)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> Large]; 

  Show[sp, pl]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity : what is Mathematica syntax for this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: pl = Plot[-x, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]; sp = StreamPlot[{1, (x - y)/(x + y)}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]; Show[sp, pl]

Comment: Thanks for answerig. Cheers :-)